# Twig: how to escape html tags for the Facebook Opengraph?

Tags: twig

I want to escape html tags in my description Opengraph tag. I have tried this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ article.text|e('html_attr') }}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ article.text|raw }}" />
```

but I still get the tags:

[image]

I have the opengraph inside `<head>`.

Comment: What about if you don't use `|raw` or `|e('html_attr')`? I mean if you get view source or `{{ dump(article.text) }}` without those escaping what will you see?

Comment: @Javad for `{{ article.text }}` I get the same result, and for `{{ dump(article.text) }}` I get `The function dump does not exist`.

Comment: The reason it comes up with that error is you are in prod mode. What I am guessing is existence of a double quot in the article.text so maybe this helps `{{ article.text|replace({'"' : "'"})|raw }}`. You can change it to anything else like **\"**

Answer (score 1):

Twig comes with a `striptags` filter ([Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html)).

Try this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ article.text|striptags }}" />
```